# Cell operations in Embedded Matlab function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to use cell operations in Embedded Matlab Function, but unfortunately it shows varargin and vararginout error.

Here is my code.

```
%# Intialization
for m = 1:365
    %# Some code
    a{m} = sum(b(:,1:144));
    c = cell2mat(a);         
    %# Size of a is 1200*365
end
```

Is there any other method to solve this is in Embedded matlab function. My code is running good in normal editor window, but showing the above errors in embedded matlab function.

Please Help..........

Comment: This is simulink, rigth? What are you triying to do?

Comment: @AnderBiguri .. Yes, it is Simulink. What I am trying to do is to find another possible solution without using cell operations. The cell operations are not supported in Embedded matlab fucntuion. In my code, the value of m gets stored in a cell called 'a' and then it is converted into matrix 'c'.

Comment: but, what is b? just a matrix? why dont you use a as a matrix then?

Comment: @AnderBiguri .; Yes, b is a matrix of size 1200*144 , whose value changes after every iteration of m.

Comment: Well b doesnt change in the code you provided... But in that code, if jou just substitute a{m} with a(m,:) it should work.

Comment: There's no way that size of `a` is 1200 x 365. Do you expect this size? is this the error that you see?